# Does Spring Integration Support Azure Service Bus?

Tags: spring-integration, amqp, azureservicebus, spring-amqp, spring-integration-amqp

I need to use Azure Service Bus for messaging, and would like to try out Spring Integration AMQP support. I can't find any related examples or anything to suggest this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If Azure Service Bus implements AMQP 1.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-overview) and Spring AMQP (https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp) provides the abstraction for any AMQP MOM, then I think it should be possible.

Remember spring-rabbit assumes you're using RabbitMQ as the AMQP implementation rather Azure Service Bus.